# CMake fails on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I am running a C++ program to test code in my C++ project. I have successfully run it using Eclipse. However, when I try to build it using CMake (for automated testing) it hits the following issue:
The cmake command resolves without problems, but when I run make, it fails with errors of the following three categories:

```
In file included from /Users/douglas/Desktop/automatedTesting/src/main.cpp:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:470:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:169:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:56:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:641:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
In file included from /Users/douglas/Desktop/automatedTesting/src/string.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/sstream:174:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:139:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/streambuf:139:5: error: 
unknown type name 'locale'
```

Along with ‘locale’ the same issue occurs with ‘streamsize’

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/streambuf:155:41: error: 
  incomplete type 'std::__1::ios_base' named in nested name specifier
```

And lastly:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:98:24: note: 
  forward declaration of 'std::__1::ios_base'
```

These errors are repeated multiple times until a total of 20 are generated, at which point it gives the following final output:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/makeTest.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/makeTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(makeTest)

set (makeTest_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (makeTest_VERSION_MINOR 0)

add_executable(makeTest src/main.cpp serial-messenger/forTest.cpp src/String.cpp src/parson.c)
target_include_directories(makeTest PRIVATE src)
target_include_directories(makeTest PRIVATE serial-messenger)
```

Environment details:

OS: Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.4

CMake: 3.13.0

CLANG: Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)

XCode is installed

I'm sure I must have made some error with setting up the environment for CMake, but I have no idea what it might be.

Edit: it looks like since Macs are case insensitive, it is mistaking my String.h file for string.h, causing the problem.

Edit 2: The problem was indeed due to Mac being case insensitive. Running it on a case sensitive OS like Linux resolves the issue.

Comment: This looks like a compilation error, not a cmake error. And this project looks like a regular executable project, it does not seem to utilize any test library.

Comment: @VTT It compiles fine when eclipse is used instead of CMake. Do you have an idea for what the cause of the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never give a **standard name** to a header with *custom* functionality!

Changing only a case (lower to upper or vice versa) isn't a good idea too.

---

According to the include chain in the error message, the **system header** file

```
.../usr/include/c++/v1/cstring
```

actually **includes** a **custom** one

```
.../automatedTesting/src/string.h
```

This is because you give a standard name `string.h` to your custom header. (Well, the actual name of the file is `String.h`, but MacOS uses a *case-insensitive* filesystem). And this is a real problem: the system header expects to obtain some standard definitions with such include, but the custom header doesn't provide them.

Rename your custom header to the *non-standard* name (e.g., `mystring.h`) and adjust your `#include` directives accordingly.

---

Comment: Well, shoot. The entire point of that was to include a String class so that the c++ program can test code written for an arduino. The actual file in automatedtesting is named String.h, not string.h, but I guess the compiler isn't noticing the difference. Will see if I can get it to pay attention to the case. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added a note about case-insensitive nature of MacOS into the answer.